# How install PC-Probe II Software related to old asus motherboard in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, motherboard

Here is my motherboard's model in asus web site:
https://www.asus.com/SupportOnly/M3A78/HelpDesk_Download/
It is very old & i am so sorry about it.
I installed windows 10 on it recently.
Every thing is working very well on win 10.
But there was a nice & useful software related to my motherboard with the name of `ASUS PC Probe II`.
Check Utility part of my motherboard.
https://www.techspot.com/downloads/265-asus-pc-probe.html
[pc probe ii asus windows 10](https://www.google.com/search?q=pc%20probe%20ii%20asus%20windows%2010&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALiCzsaJnU82NY7ky5wyawR8kpQUG3c5Xw%3A1653156704701&ei=YCuJYp6xKoGGxc8Pp9mdkA4&oq=pc%20probe%20II%20asus&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIHCCMQsAMQJzIHCAAQHhCwAzIJCAAQHhCwAxAIMgkIABAeELADEAgyCQgAEB4QsAMQCDIJCAAQHhCwAxAIMgkIABAeELADEAgyCQgAEB4QsAMQCDIJCAAQHhCwAxAIMgkIABAeELADEAhKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQAFgAYOQQaAJwAHgAgAEAiAEAkgEAmAEAyAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz)
When i tried to install win 7 of that soft on win 10 i got an error.
This motherboard is very old and asus has no support on it any more.
It seems there is a new software in microsoft store with the name of
`Probe II Sense`.
I installed it and it does n't show any information such as cpu temperature.
I think before install `ASUS PC Probe II` i should install my motherboard's driver in win 10.
Here is the files of my motherboard (win 7):
[image]
What is `AsAcpi.sys` and how can i install it on win 10 without any damage?
Give me a solution to install `ASUS PC Probe II` because this software is very important for me.

---

My motherboard driver is `ATK0110`.
I found this link on the net :
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=ACPI%5CATK0110
But i do n't know is it safe to install this driver on win 10 or not & how can i install .sys & .ini file inside of that cab file in microsoft web site.

---

Here is `PC Probe II` error during install :
[image]

---

I copied those three files from microsoft web site's driver in System32 folder of windows 10 and did restart.

After restart i could n't install PC-Probe II again.

Comment: “What is AsAcpi.sys and how can i install it on win 10 without any damage?” - It’s likely the ASUS ACPI driver, and if it doesn’t specifically support Windows 10, you don’t install it. The software you want to install likely doesn’t support Windows 10. You can certainly try installing a driver meant for Windows 7, the file is, directly from Microsoft obviously

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the comment, How can i install that win 7 driver on win 10? What is the process?

Comment: One typically doesn’t install a Windows 7 driver on Windows 10 since it’s incompatible. The error you received indicates that is in fact true with the driver your asking about. What feature of this driver do you want that the default Windows ACPI driver does not support? If that feature is that vital your only choice is to reinstall Windows 7 instead of Windows 10

Comment: I was checking cpu & motherboard temprature + cpu fan speed all the time in win 7 using with PC-Probe II and this is why i need PC-Probe II. Is there any "Accurate" software to achieve this purpose on windows 10?

Comment: There’s plenty of software that does this. If you need the driver, try installing it directly, from Device Manager. You only need the `64\WIN7` folder for that. I disagree about the chances. Because the driver does not need to conform to a Windows interface (like, say, NDIS), it is highly likely it will still work.